# Ubuntu Server 9.10 on Vmware

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, ubuntu-server

I`m trying to install Ubuntu Server 9.10 on Vmware Workstation 6.5.3.1 but the installation stucks right here:

[image]

So how do I use the interface?

Comment: Did you go through the setup already?

Comment: Yes I did...all without any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you went through the setup, you can now login there with the user account you created during setup.

Ubuntu server by itself does not include a graphical interface (X Windows et al), as that edition is for servers. If you were looking for Ubuntu desktop (with a GUI) you can grab it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download). If you don't wish to download another ISO you can use apt to install X and GNOME (the default that comes with Ubuntu desktop):

```
sudo apt-get install x-window-system-core xserver-xorg gnome-desktop-environment
```

you'll need to enable the Universe repository first then run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: But can I install Ubuntu 9.10 and then Ubuntu Server 9.10 "over it"?

Comment: that's a step backwards. You mean install a GUI on Ubuntu Server? I updated my answer with how to do that.

Comment: no, I mean...can I "enjoy" the ubuntu server features on ubuntu desktop? I need UEC.

Comment: Ah, I don't think so. Your best bet right now to save time would be to install X and GNOME if you want UEC and a GUI environment.

Comment: All official variants of the same version of Ubuntu (decktop, server, netbook, kubuntu, ...) are built from the same package repositories. They differ mainly in what packages are installed by default, and (where there are something-desktop and something-server packages for the same app/lib) some differences in default config. So start with whichever is closest to what you want and if you are missing something just find the right package name(s) and `apt-get install` or `aptitude install` (or GUI equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 9.10 - `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Ubuntu 6.06 and 8.04 - `sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment`